# How to make two objects equal to pass assertEquals()?

Tags: java, junit

So I have this code:

```
Item i = new Item(ID, TITLE, DESCRIPTION) { };
Item i2 = new Item(ID, "", "") { };
assertEquals("Item(id=1)", i.toString());
assertEquals("Item(id=1)", i2.toString());
assertNotSame(i, i2);
assertEquals(i, i2);
assertThat(0, not(equalTo(i.compareTo(i2))));

Item i3 = new Item(BigInteger.TEN, "", "") { };
assertEquals("Item(id=10)", i3.toString());
assertNotSame(i, i3);
assertThat(i, not(equalTo(i3)));
```

Also provided that:

```
@Override
public final int compareTo(final Item o) {
    int c = o.title.compareTo(title);
    if (c == 0) {
        c = o.id.compareTo(id);
    }
    return c;
}
```

It passes `assertNotSame(i, i2);` but fails at `assertEquals(i, i2);` I've tried to override `toString()` method, but that didn't help. It was actually written that `Item(id=1)` was expected and it got exactly `Item(id=1)` but there is still a problem.

I saw suggestions in other threads to override the `equals` method but don't really know how to do that.

Comment: if you using any IDE, it can generate proper equals and hashcode method for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to override the `equals(Object)` method:

```
@Override
public boolean equals (Object o) {
    if (!o instanceof Item) {
        return false;
    }
    Item other = (Item)o;
    return getId().equals(other.getId()) &&
           getTitle().equals(other.getTitle()) &&
           getDescription().equals(other.getDescription());
}
```

In order not to break Java's contract regarding `equals(Object)` and `hashCode()`, you'd need to override that too. e.g.:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    result = prime * result + getId().hashCode();
    result = prime * result + getTitle().hashCode();
    result = prime * result + getDescription().hashCode();
    return result;
}
```

**Note:** These are naive implementations assuming none of your members can be `null`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement [Object.equals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) method to provide meaningful equality test, i.e. using the attributes of your object. Also best practice dictates you should also implement hashCode() which is typically needed when using your object to behave correctly as a key in a HashMap

I see you implemented java.lang.Comparable, this is only typically used to allow sorting using Collections.sort.

It is a shame the Javadoc for [Assert.assertEquals](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html#assertEquals(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object)) makes no mention of Object.equals() for new Java programmers.

Answer (score 0):

You should override equals method. (and also the hashCode)

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for the answers. Actually all I needed was to generate `equals()` and `hashode()` methods to include only `id` field on this occasion. I did this by selecting my constructor Source > Generate hashCode() and equals()...